# Odd behavior in javascript

Tags: javascript, var

When I write this:

```
var loc = "a,a\n";
alert(loc);
```

It shows "`a...`" in alert. Then after I add some values in loc as

```
loc = loc + "abc," + valueFromFunc;
alert(loc);
```

It shows "`ab...a,a\nabc,value`" in alert. Why I get `a..` and `ab..` in loc? I want loc to be "`a,a\nabc,value`"

---

***I'm using Google Chrome. When I tried it in IE it works great but in chrome I got above output.***

Screen shot of my google chrome:

[image]

Comment: Please show EXACTLY what you code - what you have now does not make sense. _a,a\n_ will not alert `a...`

Comment: Did you mean `a,a\n` (`a,a` followed by a newline) instead of `a...`?

Comment: 'It shows "a..." in alert.' — not when I test it. It shows `a,a`, as I would have expected.

Comment: Tested in Firefox, and it shows `a,a` in the alert box for me. What browser are you testing in? Can you create a demonstration of the issue in JSFiddle?

Comment: @David: for me its showing "a...".

Comment: When I try your code the alert shows exactly what I put in the string. You've got to have some other code that is causing this. Is there any other code that may affect the result?

Comment: @Harry: What browser are you using? Could you test the same code across multiple browsers?

Comment: @mplungjan, @Lekensteyn,@Spudley, @David: see edit in my question.

Comment: @Harry: it works as expected in my chrome: `javascript:var loc="a,a\n";alert(loc)`. Just upvote this comment if you agree that "it works as expected"

Comment: @Harry Joy: If you are using some Chrome extensions,  try to disable them.

Comment: @Harry Joy:Like Lekensteyn suggested type "javascript:var loc="a,a\n";alert(loc)" directly in the chrome`s address bar. If all works fine, then you probably have some nasty plug-in in your page...

Comment: @Alex: Bakudan's answer solves my problem. Writing directly also show same output that is "a..".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that thing with the dots is from the browser. In Win Chrome it appears, but under Linux - no.

If you want to dispalay **\n** use a double slash, to show the second one.

```
var loc = "a,a\\n";
var valueFromFunc = "gdfgdfg fdgdfg";
loc = loc + "abc," + valueFromFunc;
alert(loc);
```